# How to fix Mongo "TooManyLogicalSessions" error?

Tags: mongodb

I have a sharded cluster of replica sets.  It seems I consistently run into the `TooManyLogicalSessions` error, shown below:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("d71eb685-31d3-404f-80a0-947d34d99cb9") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.5
Error while trying to show server startup warnings: Unable to add session into the cache 
because the number of active sessions is too high
```

I see some [references to this around the web](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-39044), but no real answer on how to fix it.  Is there a limit to increase somewhere, and where do I increase it?  All the mongod instances?  The config servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-39044), I ran a rolling restart of the config servers and then ran `db.getSiblingDB('config').system.sessions.drop()`, and things seem to be fixed. 
I don't really understand the side consequences of this action, though.